# simulate IE10 on windows server 2003

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-10, windows-server-2003

I have to test a aspx web application with IE10; my problem is that I have a Windows 2003 server machine.
Is there any way to simulate the behavior IE10 on this kind of machine ?
I tried IETester but it doesn't allow me to run IE10.
Can be assumed that IE10 behaves similarly to some Chrome version ?

Can you please give me a hint

Thanks a lot

Marco

Comment: Check for http://www.browserstack.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could install IE10 in any other client, and test, rather than installing the browser in the server directly.

Alternatively, if you want to test for different versions of IE, you could check out [Browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com/test-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: thanks, I'll give a look to browserstack. Did you use it on windows server 2003 ?